# Company Pages API - V1 Deprecation

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn is set to deprecate the v1 APIs on March 1st. I have a solution that uses the v1 company page APIs (https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/) to retrieve a list of updates posted to a company page.

I've read through the documentation and the migration information and unfortunately  the documentation is unclear in terms of how to get access to the updated company pages APIs.

The documentation seems to imply that in order to get access to the API's you must submit an application for approval, however the form (https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program) seems to indicate that they are accepting applications for a number of their APIs but the Company Pages API is not on the list.

At one point this page noted that access to the company pages API would not require a submission however that appears to have been removed.

I'm hoping someone has encountered this and can provide some guidance on how to proceed with getting access and if the application is required. I've tried reaching out to LinkedIn directly without much luck. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this question doesn't really ask a question about programming but of the use of an API, it would probably get answered more quickly on one of the other Stack Exchange sites, like Software Engineering or Super User.

Comment: In the form, specify you are requesting access to Community Management.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with /ugcPosts query. Ask with `q=authors` and provide a list list of companies in `authors` query parameter.

You can test it with `curl`:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer __ACCESS_TOKEN__" -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A__ORGANIZATION_ID__)"`

Dont forget to replace `__ACCESS_TOKEN__` and `__ORGANIZATION_ID__`.